# PHP Loop to Find Specific Cell Values in All Rows, where the rows contains a specific column

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have scraped a html table using simplehtmldom... the struture of the html table is ...here

`0241657 02022202143 2018000003 042018  13552   1001    Basic Pay   32340.00    0
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   1006    Dearness Allowances 7795.00 0
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   1007    House Rent Allowance    6468.00 0
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   2003    APGLI Subscription  0   1150.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   2005    GIS Ins Fund    0   60.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   2006    Professional Tax    0   200.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   2043    CPS(New GPF)    0   4014.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000003  042018  13552   2091    EHF SUBSCRIPTION    0   90.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  1001    Basic Pay   32340.00    0
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  1006    Dearness Allowances 7795.00 0
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  1007    House Rent Allowance    6468.00 0
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  2003    APGLI Subscription  0   1150.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  2005    GIS Ins Fund    0   60.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  2006    Professional Tax    0   200.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  2043    CPS(New GPF)    0   4014.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000004  052018  142720  2091    EHF SUBSCRIPTION    0   90.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  1001    Basic Pay   33220.00    0
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  1006    Dearness Allowances 8007.00 0
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  1007    House Rent Allowance    6644.00 0
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  1008    City Compensatory Allowance 0.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  1025    Interim Relief  0.00    0
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  2003    APGLI Subscription  0   1150.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  2005    GIS Ins Fund    0   60.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  2006    Professional Tax    0   200.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  2043    CPS(New GPF)    0   4123.00
0241657 02022202143 2018000009  062018  344121  2091    EHF SUBSCRIPTION    0   90.00`

Here the 4th cell(column) in the last row is 062018. 
Now How to find all the above rows which contains the same column value (4th Column of the last row... i.e.,062018) and then get the 7th,8th,9th Column values (Cell Values) of those rows to echo.

I am able to fetch values in only last row but unable to fetch the remaining above row cell values using simplehtmldom... like this

```
$mmyy = $html->find('table',1)->find('tr',-1)->find('td',3)->plaintext;
$tds = $html->find('table',1)->find('td');
foreach($tds as $td){

 if($td->plaintext == $mmyy){

    $td7 = $td->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling();
    $td8 = $td->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling();
    $basic = $td7->plaintext ;   
    $pay = $td8->plaintext ; 
    break; 
 } }

 echo $basic;
 echo $pay;
```

how to php loop and get these values... for all the rows which contains the same cell value of the 4th column of the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$input = "
<table>
<tr> <td>0241657</td> <td>02022202143</td><td>2018000003</td> <td>042018</td><td>13552</td> <td>2091</td>
<td>EHF SUBSCRIPTION</td><td>0</td><td>90</td></tr>
<tr><td>0241657</td> <td>02022202143</td><td>2018000009</td><td>062018</td> <td>344121</td><td>1006</td>
<td>Dearness Allowances</td><td>8007.00 0</td></tr>
</table>
";

function getTD($text) {
    $text = explode("<td>",$text);
    return trim($text[1]);
}

$result = array();
$input = explode("<tr>",$input); // get lines table
array_shift($input); //delete up first line

foreach($input as $str)
{
    $str = explode("</td>",$str); // get td separate
    $dt = getTD($str[3]);
    if ($dt == "062018") // you if
    {
    $tores = array();
    for($i=5; $i<8; $i++) $tores[] = getTD($str[$i]); //copy values
    $result[] = $tores;
    }
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Super Sir.. Tq Sir ... but output is in array.. 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Basic Pay [1] => 28120.00 [2] => 0 [3] => [4] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Dearness Allowances [1] => 7220.00 [2] => 0 [3] => [4] => ) [2] => Array ( [0] => House Rent Allowance [1] => 3374.00 [2] => 0 [3] => [4] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => APGLI Subscription [1] => 0 [2] => 850.00 [3] => [4] => ) [4] => Array ( [0] => GIS Ins Fund [1] => 0 [2] => 30.00 [3] => [4] => ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Professional Tax [1] => 0 [2] => 200.00 ...............) )

I am using PHP how to output as echo...